Read .bag file and need to extract all information
import bagpy
from bagpy import bagreader

b = bagreader('1.bag')

topics = b.topic_table['Topics']

for index, row in b.topic_table.iterrows():
    print(f"Topic: {row['Topics']}, Type: {row['Types']}, Messages: {row['Message Count']}, Frequency: {row['Frequency']}")

The output that I have
[INFO]  Data folder 1 already exists. Not creating.
Topic: /filtered/img_p_blur/cam_info, Type: sensor_msgs/CamInfo, Messages: 119, Frequency: 20.078224
Topic: /filtered/img_p_blur/img_raw/compressed, Type: sensor_msgs/ComImg, Messages: 119, Frequency: 28.5852
Topic: /filtered/ouster/imu_packets, Type: ouster_ros/PacketMsg, Messages: 4120, Frequency: 124.82
Topic: /filtered/ouster/lidar_packets, Type: ouster_ros/PacketMsg, Messages: 12911, Frequency: 4920.12
Topic: /received_messages, Type: can_msgs/Frame, Messages: 26257, Frequency: 4918.12


What else do you need and what prevents you from doing it?

It appears you have extracted the information; your loop outputs 5 lines of information.

I want to know the Messages for each Topic. The size of the .bag file is almost 1GB.

The details in the above sample appear to be correct, so you need to explain what your actual problem is.
